# How to pass an array created within a method to a dropdown list outside that method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help "fine-tuning" a block of code in my program which populates an array and binds that array to a dropdown list. Here is the code:

```
using ([SQL Data Connection])
{
    var stakes = from st in ddl.STK_Stakes
                 where st.STK_EVT_FK == eventId
                 select new
                 {
                     st.STK_Description
                 };

    string[] stakeDesc = new string[stakes.Count()];

    foreach (var stake in stakes)
    {
        stakeDesc[stakeCount] = stake.STK_Description;
        stakeCount++;
    }

    foundDDL.DataSource = stakeDesc;
    foundDDL.DataBind();
```

This code populates Drop-Down List "foundDDL" with options *only* when foundDDL is on the screen. ***This code works***, but as it's currently used, it is executing every time an instance of foundDDL is created on the screen.

Since the options populated in foundDDL will *always* be the same while on that page, I want to move this code to its own method, which I can then run once at load time, populate my array, and then just feed that pre-populated array to foundDDL as needed. This will reduce the number of calls to my database and make my program that much more efficient.

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to instantiate my array outside the method, since the number of spaces I'll need in the array is subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a static property?

```
private static string[] stakeDesc;
public static string[] StakeDesc {
    get {
        if(stakeDesc == null)
            //initialize it

        return stakeDesc;
    }
}
```

Comment: I gather I'm supposed to plug in the code I referenced where the "//initialize it" is. Anyway, I tried that, and the "eventId" variable in my Linq query is now throwing this error: "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'eventId'". eventId is declared in my global variables at the top of the code; why isn't it being seen here?

Comment: @bmurrell30 You probably want to make the string array static, but not the method (I'm assuming you are trying to call it in a non-static setting).

Comment: It's not being seen because it's not static.  Does `eventId` change?  if it doesn't - also make it static.  Static variables exist across all references of an object - they are in a different .. context..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify how big it is when you declare it, just declare it outside the method and instantiate it as you are already doing, and if it's already instantiated, just return it.

```
//In global scope somewhere
string[] stakeDesc;

if (stakeDesc==null || OtherReasonToRefreshData())
{
    using ([SQL Data Connection])
    {
        var stakes = from st in ddl.STK_Stakes
                     where st.STK_EVT_FK == eventId
                     select new
                     {
                         st.STK_Description
                     };

        stakeDesc = new string[stakes.Count()];

        foreach (var stake in stakes)
        {
            stakeDesc[stakeCount] = stake.STK_Description;
            stakeCount++;
        }
    }
}
foundDDL.DataSource = stakeDesc;
foundDDL.DataBind();
```

Note you can instantiate the array with 10 elements, than reassign it to a new array with 50 elements without issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, on testing this solution I found that stakeDesc will *always* return null, so the code keeps hitting the database on every request. Breakpoints tell no lies. My gut tells me, though that this just needs to be tweaked a little to get it to work the way you want.

Comment: Be sure you declare it outside of the method (that was what the comment was trying to show).  You want the array to persist after the method is called.  If it's an instance method and new objects are calling the routine, declare it as static.

Answer (score 0):

Because the information does not change, you should be caching this information instead of hitting the DB.

Roughly the code should go (have not compiled this):

```
class MyCodeBehindClass
{
    private List<string> _StakeDesc;//use a dynamically sized array
    private List<string> StakeDesc
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session[StakeDescKey] != null)
                _StakeDesc = (List<string>)Session[StakeDescKey];
            else
            {
                _StakeDesc = GetStakeDesc();
            }
            return _StakeDesc;
        }
        set { _StakeDesc = value; }
    }

    private List<string> GetStakeDesc()
    {
        using ([SQL Data Connection])
        {
            var stakes = from st in ddl.STK_Stakes
                         where st.STK_EVT_FK == eventId
                         select new
                             {
                                 st.STK_Description
                             };

            Session[StakeDescKey] = stakes.ToList();//Populate cache
        }
    }

    private void PageLoad()
    {
        //if not postback...
        foundDDL.DataSource = StakeDesc;//Smart property that checks cache
        foundDDL.DataBind();
    }
}
```